# SSEClient fails to retrieve a long stream with SSE protocol

Tags: python, server-sent-events

I'm trying to consume an SSE (Server Sent Events) stream from a server using Python. To this end, I'm trying to use `sseclient` package.

`pip install sseclient` installed version 0.0.27.

Now the program:

```
from sseclient import SSEClient
import json

url - # URL
token = # token

headers = {}
headers['Accept'] = 'text/event-stream'
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + token

messages = SSEClient(url, headers=headers)

for message in messages:
    node = json.loads(message.data)
    # process the node
```

When I consume a short stream (just a few messages), it works great.

But when I consume a stream consisting of a few thousand messages, it breaks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/romanpuchkovskiy/scripts/./search.py", line 67, in <module>
    node = json.loads(message.data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.0_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 411 (char 410)
```

Well, actually it's further processing that breaks, but this means that `sseclient` corrupts the data (so it cannot be later parsed as a `JSON`). I checked the stream with CURL using identical request, and the response is ok. It can also be successfully consumed by a client written in Java (using `WebClient` from `spring-webflux`).

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that there is a bug in `sseclient`: https://github.com/btubbs/sseclient/issues/28

It is still open, but there is a PR fixing this problem https://github.com/btubbs/sseclient/pull/35

It is not merged yet. I took the patched `sseclient.py` here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mutantmonkey/sseclient/disable_short_reads_when_chunked/sseclient.py , put it in the same directory where my script resides, and now everything works fine.